# Controller method #show getting called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have a link on my `#index` view:

```
<%= link_to 'Export Calendar (ICS)', { controller: :tickets, action: :ics_export, format: :ics }, class: "class-needed right" %>
```

`routes.rb` that pertains to this:

```
resources :tickets
get 'tickets/calendar' => 'tickets#ics_export'
post 'tickets' => 'tickets#index'
patch 'tickets/:id/close' => 'tickets#close', as: 'close_ticket'
post 'tickets/:id' => 'ticket_comments#create'
```

My `TicketsController` that pertains:

```
before_action :set_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update, :close]

def show
  @ticket_comment = TicketComment.new
end

def ics_export
  tickets = Ticket.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.ics do
      cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
      tickets.each do |ticket|
        event = Icalendar::Event.new
        event.dtstart = ticket.start
        event.description = ticket.summary
        cal.add_event(event)
      end
      cal.publish
      render :text =>  cal.to_ical
    end
  end
end

private
def set_ticket
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
end
```

And when I click the link, it takes me to `/tickets/calendar.ics` which is correct but I get the following error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TicketsController#show`

`Couldn't find Ticket with 'id'=calendar`

`Extracted source (around line #83):`

```
 private
 def set_ticket
   @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
 end
```

The `@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])` is highlighted. Which make sense that it is failing to call a ticket with an id of `calendar`.

Request has parameters:

`{"id"=>"calendar",
 "format"=>"ics"}`

How do I fix this error? Why is it calling the show action?

Comment: What if you put `get 'tickets/calendar' => ...` above `resources :tickets`? Your `rake routes` might be helpful info too, failing that.

Comment: Yes. that worked! Do you have some documentation about order of routes that could help in the future?

Comment: I'll post a more detailed answer with a link or two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a footnote in the canonical [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to the effect:

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.

As commented, the fix is to specify `get 'tickets/calendar' => ...` ahead of `resources :tickets`. If the order of routes is in question, you can run `rake routes`, which, to the best of my knowledge, should render your routes in the order they are checked.