# Routing with Parameters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm new to rails, and I'm struggling with handling the routing correctly. 
Right now I have a link called "details," and when the user clicks on it I would like the method "view_details" (within the pages controller) to be called with a location parameter that I'm passing in:

```
<%= link_to "Details", :controller => "pages", :action => "view_details", 
:location =>  v["coordinates"]%>
```

In my routes.rb file, I have:

```
get 'pages/view_details/:location', to: 'pages#view_details'
```

I am getting the following error:
    No route matches [GET] 
    "/pages/view_details/latitude=37.3505570824247&longitude=-121.922104884669"

When I rake routes, I see this (with no prefix):
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you share the rake routes output?, what is prefix of the routes?

Comment: just edited the post, see the inserted picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a *hash* as a value for `location` parameter so, instead of just adding one parameter (i.e. `location`), it adds two parameters (i.e. `latitud` and `longitude`) and your routing fails.

To fix this you could set your route without `location`, like this:

```
get 'pages/view_details', to: 'pages#view_details'
```

Now, using the same link you have now, you will receive `latitud` and `longitude` parameters grouped in `location` as a **query string**, something similar to:

```
pages/view_details?location%5Blatitude%5D=37.3505570824247&location%5Blongitude%5D=121.922104884669
```

And you can use them in your controller with `params` (as with any other parameter), for example:

```
latitude = params[:location][:latitude]
longitud = params[:location][:longitude]
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the error I was getting. However now it seems to be calling the pages#show action and displaying the pages/show view. The view_details action isn't being executed at all. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: nevermind, I was able to fix it using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633639/controller-method-show-getting-called