# ruby on rails call external api and show results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, model-view-controller, jsonplaceholder

I'm trying to call API (to like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/). the idea is simple click the button to show the res but I'm having trouble implementing it. What I have below is just the button calling the function and want to print it in the console.

error:

`enter code here No route matches [POST] "/dashboard/fetch_action"`

routes

```
resources :dashboard do
 collection do
   get :fetch_action
 end
end
```

dashboard_controller.er

```
require 'faraday'

def index
end

def fetch_action
    response = Faraday.get 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    puts response
    # return response 
end
```

index.html.erb

```
    <%= button_to "fetch action", fetch_action_dashboard_index_path, class: "btn btn-warning" %>
```

Thank you

EDIT:

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  
  devise_scope :user do
    root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  end

  get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'
  get '/dashboard/fetch-action', to: 'dashboard#fetch_action', as: 'dashboard_fetch_action'
  get '/user' => 'dashboard#index', :as => :user_root

end
```

rake routes

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
            user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#cancel
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
        user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
                     root GET    /                                                                                        devise/sessions#new
                dashboard GET    /dashboard(.:format)                                                                     dashboard#index
   dashboard_fetch_action GET    /dashboard/fetch-action(.:format)                                                        dashboard#fetch_action
                user_root GET    /user(.:format)                                                                          dashboard#index
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

index.html.eb

```
<%= link_to "fetch action", dashboard_fetch_action_path, class: "btn btn-info" %>

<%= @response %>
```

fetch-action.html.erb

```
<%= @response %>
```

dashboard_controller

```
def index
end

def show
end

def fetch_action
    uri = URI('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    req = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    @response = JSON.parse(req)
end
```

Error (when clicking the link_to redirects to dashboard/fetch-action with the following error):

`DashboardController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.`

Comment: Why are you using "puts" rather than "respond_to" in the controller?

Comment: the fetch_action method needs to return a json value, so the last line should be render json: response

Comment: the button_to element needs to generate a GET request to match your configured route. So add method: :get into the button_to parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## troubleshooting and setting routes

First, in your terminal, run `rake routes` to print out the routes in your app. Post that output here. But you’ll want to check the output of that command for the `fetch_action_dashboard_index_path` you’re using in the button - is that the correct path?

I assume it’s not. And there is a simpler way to declare one route. What you’re doing with the resources declaration in your route is configuring routes for the index, show, create, update and delete actions for The dashboard controller. The below line in your routes.rb file will setup just the fetch_action route and name it “dashboard_fetch_action”

`get '/dashboard/fetch-action', to: 'dashboard#fetch_action', as: 'dashboard_fetch_action'`

## creating a link to that route

Second; use `link_to` instead of button_to to ensure you make a GET request. The btn classes you’re applying will style that link to look like a button anyway and an `a` tag is more semantically correct than `button` (because you want to GET) so use:

`<%= link_to "fetch action", dashboard_fetch_action_path, class: "btn btn-warning" %>`

## rendering the results of the action

Finally make sure you have a file in `app/views/dashboard/fetch_action.html.erb` which will render the API response as HTML. This content (or similar) will achieve that.

`<%= @response =>`

And, in your fetch_action action in the dashboard controller. Instead of `response = Faraday...`, use `@response = Faraday...`. That way the `response` object can be accessed in the view HTML (that’s what the @ signifies)

```
def fetch_action
    @response = Faraday.get 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I'm having trouble rendering in the same current page? I changed the action method instead of return to `render @response` (and added response in the views `<%= @response %>) but that didn't seem to show anything

Comment: You don’t `render` or `return` your response. You make it an “instance variable”, so it can be used in the view. Have a read of https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/ruby-scope-binding/ and I’ll update the answer to be more specific.

Comment: While you don’t end your actions with `return`, and you don’t need to end them with `render`, in my example above, rails is assuming I want a standard `respond_to` block. It’s a bit of magic.

Comment: I tried that as well, without returning and using the instant variable however it still redirects (obviously due to route, so I added `:remote => true` and that's where the it doesn't show it after click. I looked through the docs of link_to but also couldn't find anything that would work? the latest I had was to remove the path and do it by adding controller and action `<%= link_to "fetch action", controller: "dashboard", action: "fetch_action"%>`

Comment: You’re adding complexity by taking the above approach - complexity you’re struggling to understand and it’s not fixing things for you. 

When you add remote: true you’re telling Rails to render the `app/views/dashboard/fetch_action.js.erb` Note the js instead of html - which may not be what you want and certainly isn’t what you’ve set yourself up to serve.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to include how to create a named route so you don’t need to specify the action and controller in the link_to and I’ve been more explicit about exactly how the code should be. 

If you implement what’s described in the answer, what happens?

Comment: And feel free to update your question with the output of `rake routes` And what your code looks like now - the view files, routes.rb and the controller

Comment: Thanks again, updated post with `rake routes`. what i tried now was to remove the `get :fetch_action` and use what you suggested above `get/dashboard/fetch-action...` as well removed the `fetch_action_dashboard_index_path` from the view as it was not recognized instead have `dashboard_fetch_action_path` (from routes as well) but the error seems to be dashboard controller method `show` is not configured properly I believe (I'm looking over it now)

Comment: Can you post the full error in an update to your question? As well as the full code of the link_to and the route you added? I’llm not sure I know what you mean by keeping the get fetsh_action but removing it from the routes.rb ...??? Post clear examples of the code as it stands.

Comment: Updated the post with the parts needed. the error I was getting I fixed (had the fetch_action.html.erb as a partial `_` removed that) though it's still opening to the new page rather than the index where `@response` is>

Comment: Thanks for updating. Is that the full route file and the full dashboard controller or have you snipped it for brevity?

Comment: The error message shows that you’re calling the dashboard#show action instead of fetch_action. God knows how( your link_to is setup correctly. To better troubleshoot, can you visit the fetch_action url manually instead of clicking the link, that way you can tell where the problem might be. Just enter `localhost:3000/dashboard/fetch-action` In your browser and see what happens.

Comment: the routes I snipped though dashboard is full, I'll update with the complete. thought I tested again manually going to the route and still showed the same error :/ yea i'm so lost why it's calling it, a quick search I found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633868/13836628) so i'll try that (at first I thought that I have to specify in the show method how to deal with the `@response` maybe?

Edit:

Comment: Edit:
I restarted the server and now working fine (not calling show) but still in a new page rather than the index? I see that it's kind of what is expected since from the url route given too

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming your template to `fetch_action.html.erb`?

As far as I know, Rails wants the template name to match the action name, which is probably `fetch_action` because Ruby methods cannot contain a dash `-`. The dash character is used for subtraction, which is why it's not valid in a method name.

Comment: Yep, I got it to work! though I was wanting it to show the response in the index page (current page)

Comment: If this is the solution to your question then please mark it as the answer.